# Memory error debugging in complex program with many threads and processes in Python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, memory-management, multiprocessing

I'm struggling to debug memory usage/leak issues in a complex program with extensive use of threading and multiprocessing (e.g., thousands of concurrent threads and dozens (or potentially hundreds) of concurrent processes).

A.  I've tried running the [memory_profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) in the hopes of getting the line-by-line output, but it seems that it does not produce this output until the program is complete.  I am encountering two issues with this:

(i) My program is designed to run indefinitely.  I've tried some simple modifications to end my program after a certain point (at least in the main process/thread), but the children threads and processes continue to run, and so, I do not get the memory_profiler output.

(ii) Because the children threads and processes continue to run as mentioned in (i), it seems to me that I would need to do fairly significant re-designing to get the children threads and processes to stop when the main thread / process stops.  (I've been contemplating creating a global variable to use as a halt flag in the threads and using the [multiprocessing state sharing capabilities](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) to share that halt flag with the children processes, but I suspect my approach here is wrong / unnecessarily complex).

B.  I've tried objgraph (referenced here: https://benbernardblog.com/tracking-down-a-freaky-python-memory-leak/), which allows me to print memory usage and growth tables as the program runs (e.g., using [objgraph.show_most_common_types() and objgraph.show_growth()](https://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/)).  But, I found the output to be unhelpful.  It essentially tells me I have 60 gb of data in lists, but I'm not seeing a way to break down that information on a variable-by-variable, thread-by-thread and/or process-by-process basis.

I have the following questions:

1. Regarding the memory_profiler:

   (i)  Is there a way to get the line-by-line output of memory_profiler without the program running to completion?

   (ii)  Is there a way to kill the children threads and processes without going down the complex path I suggested above in (A)(ii)?
2. Is there a way to get more detailed information about memory usage from objgraph?
3. I use PyCharm as my IDE and am familiar with its profiling capabilities for speed analysis, but I don't see any memory analysis in its profiling capabilities.  Am I missing it?
4. Are there better / easier to use memory analysis tools for debugging Python scripts than what I've referenced above?  I'm open to both free and paid options.
5. Is there a relatively straightforward way count how many threads and processes I've launched across different threads and processes (i.e., globally)?  I've used the multiprocessing [is_alive()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.is_alive) and threading [isAlive()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.isAlive) functions within specific threads/processes.  But, I don't see a relatively straightforward way to count the number of threads and processes globally without implementing a entire framework using queues, global variables and state sharing to count that information (which would be used just for debugging).
6. Perhaps this is too broad of a question, but am I going about the memory usage debugging incorrectly?  If so, do you have recommendations for different techniques (or for sources that illustrate different techniques)?

Comment: Yes, your approach in A(ii) makes sense, it's worthwhile getting a HALT flag to work so threads will see it and exit. Item B(5) is addressed using external tools like `ps` and similar, to see processes and threads. For B(6), create a threaded synthetic workload that resembles some aspect of production, and crank it up until you deterministically reproduce the races / leaks you see in production. The simpler workload will be easier to instrument & analyze. Sorry, that's a lot of work. Debugging is hard, especially debugging races. Best to deliberately provoke them so they're out in the open.

Comment: Thank you, @J_H.  Good to know my ideas are not outside the norm.  Agreed that debugging is hard, but the premise of my questions are whether there are tools that make it that much easier to debug memory issues.  In my search, I came across Intel's profiling tool, VTune (https://software.intel.com/en-us/vtune-amplifier-help-python-code-analysis?fbclid=IwAR1eLx0ddcKaEC1xrTGso3USOJ-Tkn3Jphh-XCcQ_VNvIyKtvCVNghX0Uec).  I haven't had a chance to try it, but it looks interesting.  Would appreciate if anyone has any thoughts on Intel's tool, particularly in terms of ease of use and usefulness.

Comment: Hello @dan, had the same problem with memory leaks in infinite python app. Did you found way how to debug it? If yes share please. Thanks!